# ASP.NET MVC: How to do post operation after response has been sent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that is responsible for persisting a record in DB, upon success, it has to send an email to Admin. This end point is used by APP and sending email before API response can increase wait time. So instead of sending email after record has been persisted, I want to send after controller sends the response to APP.

I googled for it but not able to find concrete answer. I thought starting point could be action filter.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code or what you have tried for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement a notification service and just add messages to a queue, that way the controller doesn't have to wait for the email to be sent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...  I have done something like this before but looking for some lightweight solution.

Comment: I agree this could be one of solutions.. I accept you answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ResultFilter:

```
public class MailSenderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //your code...
    }
}

...
[MailSenderAttribute]
public ActionResult YourAction() { /*code*/ }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have tried that but OnResultExecuted is not designed to achieve this because response will still wait on this before sending to client.

Answer (score 0):

Because after response is sent from controller to client, MVC lifecycle will end so action filters does not help. Also agree with NachoMK. I think we can implement something as suggested in this blog by Scott Hanselman. 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx